# Enum Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String (Grails)

Tags: grails, enums

I'm quite new to grails and making my mini project. Grails version 2.4.5. I have a Rental class with status as enum. I know that I have to create a class inside /src/groovy.

```
package ers

enum EquipmentStatusEnum {
    Available ("Available"),
    Rented ("Rented")

    String name

    EquipmentStatusEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

Domain Class Rental

```
package ers

class Rental implements Serializable {

    Date dateRented

    EquipmentStatusEnum status

    ClientAccount account
    Equipment equipment

    static constraints = {
        status shared:"gc", inList: EquipmentStatusEnum.values()*.name
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite:['account', 'equipment']
    }
}
```

With that in mind, I'm trying to populate my database table in Bootstrap.groovy

```
new Rental(account:ClientAccountInstance1, equipment:EquipmentInstance1, dateRented: new Date("April 7, 2017"), status:'Available').save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
new Rental(account:ClientAccountInstance2, equipment:EquipmentInstance3, dateRented: new Date("April 8, 2017"), status:'Available').save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
new Rental(account:ClientAccountInstance3, equipment:EquipmentInstance5, dateRented: new Date("April 9, 2017"), status:'Available').save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
```

But after running my application. An error occured saying:

```
| Error 2017-04-19 16:02:29,589 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: ers.EquipmentStatusEnum cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Message: ers.EquipmentStatusEnum cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

What seems to be the problem? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should be using enum values instead of strings there

Comment: How can I do just that?

Comment: `new Rental(.., status:EquipmentStatusEnum.Available ).save(..)`

Comment: Got the same error, but after commenting the constraints for status. It already work. The problem is with my global constraints declared in config.groovy